# vb.net how to ignore empty data from database with datepicker

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I need help on how can to skip a data if cell is empty. Because not all datas have a date on it.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick


    If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value Or DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value = Nothing Then

    Else
        Guna2DateTimePicker1.Value = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString
        Guna2DateTimePicker3.Value = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString
    End If
```

Comment: First things first, why are you calling `ToString` on a cell value and then assigning the result to a property of type `Date`? DO NOT call `ToString` unless you specifically want a string representation of something. It's not a general tool of convenience to use everywhere. Things that are not `Strings` should not be arbitrarily converted to `Strings`.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in that question that relates to MySQL, so you should not have applied the MySQL tag. I've removed it. Only add tags that are relevant to the issue. What database the data came from in the first place has zero bearing on what you're doing. I have also added tags that are relevant. Put a bit more thought into your tags in future. If you don't know what tags are relevant then you probably haven't analysed the problem sufficiently to be asking a question in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```vb
If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value Or
   DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value = Nothing Then
```

What that code is actually doing is this:

```vb
If (DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value = True) Or
   (DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value = Nothing) Then
```

That is clearly not what you intended. The proper way to write the code based on your intention would be this:

```vb
If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value Is Nothing OrElse
   DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value Is Nothing Then
```

Note the multiple changes there. It is comparing both cell values instead of one, it is short-circuiting using `OrElse` rather than `Or` and it is using `Is` rather than `=` because `Value` is type `Object`. You should turn `Option Strict On` in your project properties and also in your VS options and the compiler will flag many places where you have written bad code like this.

That said, it's probably still wrong. That's because, if you are using ADO.NET for data access, NULL fields will contain `DBNull.Value`, not `Nothing`, so that's what you should be checking for:

```vb
If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value Is DBNull.Value OrElse
   DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
```

Finally, it's terrible practice to test for a positive condition, have an empty `If` block and then put your code in the `Else` block. If you are only interested in the negative condition then test for the negative condition in the first place:

```vb
If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso
   DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
    '...
End If
```

Notice the flipping of the comparison operators and the Boolean operator.

Comment: Thanks, after many trial and errors. This one seems to help my problem